# XSL variable in curly braces

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, curly-braces

I am using xsl to add tag with attribute to xml. I need to do this with condition `w:t="${para1}"`. When hardcode `para1`, the process work. But , when I define $variable='para1' and use $variable inside curly braces `{` `}` , it did not work.

tried the following:

1. `${`$variable`}`
2. define left and right braces as variable. then concat(left,variable,right)
3. Double the left and right braces ${{$variable}}

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <w:document xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
     xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
     xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
     xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
     xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
     xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
     xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
     xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
     xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <w:body>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>${para1}</w:t>
       </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

xsl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    >
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="variable">para1</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute_id">1</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match='w:p[w:r/w:t="${para1}"]'>
    <!--<xsl:variable name="left">${</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="right">}</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match='w:p[w:r/w:t="concat($left,$variable,$right)"]'>-->
    <!--<xsl:template match='w:p[w:r/w:t="${$variable}"]'>--><!--para1 should be variable-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="w:id"> <xsl:value-of select="$attribute_id" /></xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[editcodeonline](http://xsltransform.net/jxN9j9e/2)

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for, XSLT 1,2,3 share attribute value templates, the relevant section of the XSLT 3.0 spec is https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-value-templates, XSLT 3 additionally has text value templates as a feature you can enable https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates. Dynamic XPath evaluation is also a feature new in XSLT 3 as part of the language and these days supported in current XSLT 3 processors like Saxon 10 or later, SaxonJS 2.

Comment: You have, however, restricted the question to XSLT 1.0, there a few, I think libxslt based processors, support EXSLT `dyn:evaluate`.

Answer (score 0):

This works in XSLT 3.0 but I haven't tested with 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    >
      
    <xsl:variable name="para1">ReplacementValue</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="w:p/w:r/w:t/text()[matches(., '[$][{]para1[}]')]">
      <xsl:value-of select="$para1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces this output with the hardcoded `para1` variable, which could instead come from a stylesheet parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><w:document xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <w:body>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>ReplacementValue</w:t>
       </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:body>
    </w:document>
```